# Проблемы с типами данных на хостинге php Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

На локале php7.1, проблема в том, что на хостинге при полечении данных с БД через модели - данные типа integer конвертируются в string(почему-то, хотя локально все хорошо), и все проверки !==, ===, in_array - не работают.

В чем может быть причина?

На сервере mysql 5.7

Модель:

```
<?php

namespace App\Components\TaskManagement\Models\DB;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
* @property int $id
* @property string $entity
* @property float $progress
* @property string $error
* @property int $external_id
* @property int $status
* @property string $created_at
* @property string $updated_at
*/
class TaskManagement extends Model
{
/**
 * The table associated with the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'tasks_management';

/**
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = ['created_at', 'progress', 'error', 'entity', 'external_id', 'status', 'updated_at'];
```

Пример запроса:

```
public function getFiltered(array $search = [], $pageSize = 5): LengthAwarePaginator
{
    $query = TaskManagement::query();

    return $query->paginate($pageSize);
}
```

Данная проверка не работает, потому-что поле status конвертируется в string, повторюсь, что на локале все работает:

```
@elseif($task->status === \App\Components\Task\Models\DB\UserTask::STATUS_DONE)
```

Comment: пример модели и запроса можно увидеть? хостинг обычно не влияет на такие вещи

Comment: Дополнил вопрос